# Aluminum fork: paint defect or sign of strained?

Tags: road-bike, fork, aluminum, paint

I know there's a lot of question regarding paint defect or crack.
But I need your opinion about this.
Recently, I bought new bike but discounted and it's the last piece of it.
On the back of the aluminum fork has this appearance:
[image: left side-back of fork]
[image: right-side-back of fork]

I thought it's really about paint defect or it isn't?
What's the possibility if somehow deformed?
I didn't see or feel any problem when attaching the front wheel and when riding it.
Means that there's no apparent bent or misalignment between left/right fork.
I'm really curious. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's a paint defect.

Aluminum would not stretch enough to flake the paint off like that without staying deformed or actually cracking.

If the fork or wheel had suffered a collision into a solid object that had bent the fork, you'd see evidence in the paint on both the front and back edges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I check the front side, yes,  they are smooth.

Comment: I had a similar thing on my old bike but the mechanic said it was just the paint.

Comment: I don't know if I'd venture the guess that if the fork were flexed you'd see paint defects on both sides. That would depend on whether the paint had better tensile than compression strength as cured. I don't know either. It *ought* to be powder coat, and not liquid paint. The orange peel on the inside near the vent hold is evidence of lousy surface prep, and that is likely the cause of the cracking as well.